# Inequality for the magnitude of quiver algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

A conjecture on the global dimension of quiver algebras of finite global dimension states that the global dimension is bounded by the vector space dimension of the algebra.
The magnitude of a finite dimensional algebra with finite global dimension is defined as the sum of entries of the inverse of the Cartan matrix of the algebra ,see https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04281.

The analogue question would be:

> Question: Is the magnitude of a quiver algebra with finite global dimension bounded by the dimension of the algebra?

Note that this can be translated into the more funny form asking whether the sum of all entries of the Cartan matrix is larger than or equal to the sum of all entries of the inverse matrix.